# SQL Server insert table data script with new Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database that all tables are multi-company (column "`masterentity`"). All my Identity columns are Auto-increment integers.

I want to generate a insert script of all my data but associate it to another "company". Right now I'm generating the Data Only option but I get all `INT` primary keys and of course when I try to insert I get an error because that primary key already exists with other company.

[image]

Actually, what I want is to clone all the data on my tables but for other company (masterentity), is that possible? I know if I have GUID's as primary keys that's easy because but having `INT` as primary key I think its a little bit complicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to duplicate the data for another company, you can do a simple `INSERT/SELECT`, something like this... :

```
INSERT INTO YourTable ( CompanyId, some_data, other_data )
SELECT **Enter your company id here** , some_data, other_data FROM YourTable
```

Just omit your id column, it'll be auto-generated by sql-server.

If you want your ids to be the same, you'll have to include the CompanyId to the Primary key because the PK should, by definition, be unique.